# Array to String conversion troubles

Tags: php, arrays, oop, foreach, upload

so I am struggling with this bit of code for a project that I am working on. I do not understand why I am getting an array to string conversion error for my use of the Move_uploaded_file function below, since I implemented a foreach loop to work only with each individual element in the array. Also note that the issue- according to php's error handling- is specifically with the move_uploaded_file function, not with the other methods that get called.

Here's the relevant code. (Thanks all for the help).

```
public function relocate () {

    foreach ($this->getFilename() as $name) {
        $validate = $this->validatePhoto($name); 
        $size = $this->getSize($name); 

        if ($validate && $size) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($name, $this->filepath . $this->getFilename())) {
                echo "<p> upload complete </p>"; 
                //rename file, redirect header, etc. 
            } //end if move_uploaded_file
            else {
                echo "<p> something's up. </p>"; 
            }//end else 
        }//end if validate && size
    }//end foreach
}//end relocate method
```

Comment: `$this->getFilename()` returns an array.  You are looping over that, why are you then trying to add the array to a string?  `$this->filepath.$name`

Comment: You're using `$this->getFilename()` **both** in the foreach (as an array), *and* in the `move_uploaded_file` function (as a string)

Comment: Because `$this->getFilename()` is returning an array (the one you're iterating over in the first place) but you're then trying to pretend that it isn't an array in your `move_uploaded_file()`.... Why not `if (move_uploaded_file($name, $this->filepath . $name)) {`

Comment: wow, I did not realize that. I was thinking something was wrong with how I looped. Stupid error on my part, thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should replace `$this->getFilename()` with `$name`, `$this->getFilename()` returns an array if I got it right...

```
public function relocate () {

    foreach ($this->getFilename() as $name) {
        $validate = $this->validatePhoto($name); 
        $size = $this->getSize($name); 

        if ($validate && $size) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($name, $this->filepath . $name)) {
                echo "<p> upload complete </p>"; 
                //rename file, redirect header, etc. 
            } //end if move_uploaded_file
            else {
                echo "<p> something's up. </p>"; 
            }//end else 
        }//end if validate && size
    }//end foreach
}//end relocate method
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
public function relocate () {

    foreach ($this->getFilename() as $name) {
        $validate = $this->validatePhoto($name); 
        $size = $this->getSize($name); 

        if ($validate && $size) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($name, $this->filepath . $name)) {
                echo "<p> upload complete </p>"; 
                //rename file, redirect header, etc. 
            } //end if move_uploaded_file
            else {
                echo "<p> something's up. </p>"; 
            }//end else 
        }//end if validate && size
    }//end foreach
}//end relocate method
```

You're passing in `$this->getFileName()` to `move_uploaded_file()`, when you should be passing in `$name`, as you're already iterating over the array that `$this->getFileName()` is returning